# Can Terraform conditionally create a resource or use a data source?

Tags: terraform

I have a Boolean called "loose", based on it's value I want to use an existing resource or create one, let say a security group. I would like to avoid using terragrunt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Terraform allows you to conditionally create a resource or use a data source based on the value of a variable. You can use the count parameter along with the count function to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. The simple case with count = 0 is not what I am asking. For example if a dns zone exists I dont want to attempt to create one, but if it doesn't I want my resource to be created.